# Group multiple cases together in the switch statement

Tags: c++

Here below is my code for a switch statement:

```
 switch(pin)
  {
  case 1:
    break;
  case 2:   case 3:  case 4:  case 5:  case 6:  case 7:  case 8:  case 9:  case 10:  case 11:
  case 12:  case 13:  case 14:  case 15:  case 16:  case 17:  case 18:  case 19:  case 20:
  case 21:  case 22:  case 23: case 24:case 25:case 26:case 27:case 28:case 29: case 30: case 31:
  case 32: case 33: case 34: case 35:

    dataOut[pin-2] = 1;
    DAQmxWriteDigitalLines(taskHandleOut,1,1,10.0,DAQmx_Val_GroupByChannel,dataOut,NULL,NULL);

    break;

  default:
    break;
```

In the above, the case 2-35 are to be grouped together for which, I mean, when `pin` is equal to 2-35, the specific task is to be performed.

I want to know if the above code is valid or not. I haven't seen case grouping in switch statements. Any weblinks for similar multiple case grouping is appreciated. Maybe there is some better way to do so instead of grouping multiple cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your case may be better served with an if-check `if (pin >= 2 && pin <= 35)`, it *is* common to group case labels like that.

gcc/clang/tinycc even have syntactic sugar for it:

```
switch(pin){
case 2 ... 35: /*nonstandard GNU extension; note well the whitespace*/
};
```

Comment: One big advantage of this is that it makes it explicit that all the numbers from 2 to 35 inclusive are treated alike.  With the wall of case statements, it would be very easy to deliberately or accidentally omit one, and it wouldn't be obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is absolutely fine, although I'd write

```
if (pin >= 2 && pin <= 35){
    dataOut[pin-2] = 1;
    DAQmxWriteDigitalLines( ...
}
```

if I were you. If you are using gcc exclusively as your compiler, then you could also use [case ranges](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html).

Answer (score 3):

It is valid. It's called **fallthrough**, and it's the reason you have to put `break`s to separate `case`s. That is, if you don't `break`, the instructions following your case will get executed anyway. Like in

```
int i = 1;
switch(i) {
    case 1:
        cout<<1<<endl;
    case 2:
        cout<<"nope!\n";
}
```

This will output

```
1
nope!
```

because there's no `break` before `case 2:`.

But in your case you may as well do

```
if (pin >= 2 && pin <= 35) {
    dataOut[pin-2] = 1;
    DAQmxWriteDigitalLines(taskHandleOut,1,1,10.0,DAQmx_Val_GroupByChannel,dataOut,NULL,NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. C++ provides *fall-through* for `switch` case statements. So unless you provide a `break;` at the end of the `case:`, control *falls-through* to the next case allowing you to do exactly what you describe with a switch. Some compilers allow short-hand for describing multiple case statements at once, but for portable C++, simply providing each case without a `break;` is all you need, e.g.

```
switch(pin)
{
    case 1:
        break;
    case  2: case  3: case  4: case  5: case  6: case  7: case  8: case  9: 
    case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15: case 16: case 17: 
    case 18: case 19: case 20: case 21: case 22: case 23: case 24: case 25: 
    case 26: case 27: case 28: case 29: case 30: case 31: case 32: case 33: 
    case 34: case 35:
        /* do what you need with pins 2 - 35 */
        dataOut[pin-2] = 1;
        DAQmxWriteDigitalLines (taskHandleOut, 1, 1, 10. 0, 
                            DAQmx_Val_GroupByChannel, dataOut, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Now any case `2-35` will execute your desired statements:

```
        dataOut[pin-2] = 1;
        DAQmxWriteDigitalLines (taskHandleOut, 1, 1, 10. 0, 
                            DAQmx_Val_GroupByChannel, dataOut, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's valid code but I would rather use default in your case especially when you have planned to use other numbers for other cases. default will be used like else in an if/else statement. Here default would be called for every number you don't have an case specified.

Comment: `default:` is a bad solution. It will also get hit by any (invalid) value not in the range you intended.

Comment: I would say in this particular case he described it's more default than anything else but it's right, when the code shouldn't do this in case of any other number this would be a bad solution. But I would recommand doing this nevertheless and would add the if statement from other posts into the default case because it's much cleaner and more readable and you can use the other cases of the switch case too. So if he wants to add functions for case 36 or case -1 he can just use another case of the switch case instead of using more if statements.